# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted

Tags: python

html

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label">
        "Status"
        <span>&nbsp;*</span>
    </label><select name="immunizationStatusId" class="custom-select">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="18401">Up-to-Date – Complete </option>
        <option value="18402">Up-to-Date – In Series </option>
        <option value="18403">Up-to-Date – Disease </option>
        <option value="18404">Up-to-Date – Immunity </option>
        <option value="18405">Delinquent </option>
        <option value="18406">Exempt – Medical </option>
        <option value="18407">Exempt – Conscientious </option>
        <option value="18408">Provisional Enrollment </option>
    </select>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

in python:

```
dropdown_stuimmunizationstatus_xpath = (By.XPATH, "//*[@name='immunizationStatusId']")
self.dropdown_valueselection(self.dropdown_stuimmunizationstatus_xpath, stuimmunizationstatus)
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element . .. is not clickable at point (1400, 38). Other element would receive the click: <div class="general-loader" style="d

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error message and I have resolved like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

service = Service(r'C:\Users\91990\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\WCYM1\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
url = r'https://www.flipkart.com/'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
# driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Login").click()
# driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a._1_3w1N").click()
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/account/login?ret=/']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button) # This line very important
```